# Finding the address of nested structure member variables

Tags: c

Dear stackoverflow Enthusiasts,

First of all I am a novice in stackoverflow, so I apologise in advance for any mistakes I commit.

This is kind of a C puzzle. or atleast I was puzzled by it. The code is given below.

```
struct outer_str
{
  struct nest_str1
  {
     int mem1;
  };
  struct nest_str2
  {
     int mem2;
  }nest_var2;
}outer_var;

int main()
{
   outer_var.nest_var2.mem2 = 111;
   printf("\n\nThe value of mem2 is %d\n\n",outer_var.nest_var2.mem2);

   // Statement to assign mem1 of nest_str1 with a value say 333;
   // Statement to print the value of mem1 of nest_str1;

   return 0;
}
```

As the comments suggest you have to access the member variable **mem1** of the nested structure **nest_str1**. Also please note that there are no structure variables declared for the nested structure nest_str1.

Hoping against hope I tried the following code, imitating a bit of C++.

```
outer_var.nest_str1.mem1=333;
```

When I compiled the program using GCC 4.6.3, The following error was shown

```
"struct outer_str has no member named 'nest_str1' ".
```

Then I thought about finding the address of nest_str1 from the address of **nest_var2** which is the structure variable of nested structure **nest_str2**. I tried the following code,

```
int main()
{
 int offset;
 struct nest_str1 * addr; 
 offset=sizeof(int); // There is only one integer mem1 in nest_str1
 addr=(struct nest_str1 *)((int *) & (outer_var.nest_var2) - offset);
 addr->mem1=333;
 printf("\n\nThe value of mem1 is %d\n\n",addr->mem1);
 return 0;
}
```

The program compiled O.K. But the output was not what I expected. I got a run time error.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now I don't even know whether my approach was correct or not. So I am hoping for some suggestions. I am also worried that I might have overlooked some obviously simple solution.

I would also like to know whether we can access **mem1** in the code given below.

```
struct outer_str
{

  struct nest_str1
  {
     int mem1;
  };

}outer_var;
```

I thank every one in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: Some folks need to be careful about this, because the syntax above is accepted by some compilers.  They would consider `nest_str1` to be an anonymous (or unnamed) member of the structure and allow access to _its_ members "directly", as in: `outer_var.mem1 = 7;` would compile fine.  But is it definitely **not portable**!  (This was added just for reference, because some folks can get away with it and others cannot -- and there are many readers here...)

Comment: @SteveValliere, that would be the case if the structure is anonymous, i.e. not named as above. (`struct { int mem1; };`) AFAIK

Comment: @Nim the presence of the structure _tag_ doesn't affect whether or not an _instance_ of the structure is anonymous or not.  You could name an instance of a structure without a tag, then you cannot reuse the structure definition anywhere else (because it is anonymous.)  That's probably not clear, sorry.  That's kinda why I thought it worth mentioning that anonymous members should generally be avoided whenever possible -- they are confusing and non-portable.

Comment: @SteveValliere Not sure how it's in C++, but in C, "An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier **with no tag** is called an _anonymous structure_; an unnamed member whose type specifier is a union specifier **with no tag** is called an _anonymous union_." (Bold parts emphasised by me, italics in the original.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I use MSVC for most of my work and got my terms from the documentation that came with it.  For example <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f.aspx>  The fist line says _"A Microsoft C extension allows you to declare a structure variable within another structure without giving it a name. These nested structures are called anonymous structures. C++ does not allow anonymous structures."_  I can say for certain that it applies to their plain C compiler as well -- we don't use C++ for any of the nearly 1,000,000 lines of code we wrote and maintain.

Comment: @SteveValliere Ah, okay. They have been added to the standard only in C2011, so before that, the term was not defined in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no member of `outer_var` that will allow you to access `mem1` (you've not declared one, you just defined a *type* called `nest_str1`.)

Change this to:

```
struct outer_str
{

  struct nest_str1
  {
     int mem1;
  } nest_var1;  // now there is a member!

}outer_var;
```

Now you can:

```
outer_var.nest_var1.mem1 = 100;
```

Your attempt is just plain wrong, there is no storage for `mem1`, so even if your code worked, you would most likely end up writing to the location of `mem2`.

Comment: Thank you. But what will happen when the structure variable outer_var of structure outer_str is created?

Comment: But I have subtracted offset from the address of mem2.

Comment: Hence the segfault, you are writing into some random memory location, as I said, there is no *storage* for `mem1`, gcc by default does not treat your first structure as an *anonymous* structure (you have named it, so, it's treated as a *type*). Remove the name, and then `mem1` will be accessible from `outer_var` as `outer_var.mem1`)

Comment: Now when I have changed the code as follows, it is not showing any error.    addr=(struct nest_str1 *)((char *) & (outer_var.nest_var2) - offset); Now I have no idea where the data is being stored.

Comment: But why are you doing this? If `nest_str1` is being treated as an anonymous structure member, you should be able to access `mem1` directly as - `outer_var.mem1 = 333`, if you cannot `mem1` does not exist in the layout of `outer_str`, so anything you do is going to invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The code written by you is absolutely right. But while subtracting the "offset" value from second nested structure "outer_var.nest_var2", in spite of typecasting it to (int *) just typecast it to (char*) i.e "addr=(struct nest_str1 *)((char *) & (outer_var.nest_var2) - (char *)offset);" and you will be able to populate the variable inside the first structure.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct outer_str{
        struct nest_str1
  {
     int mem1;
  };
  struct nest_str2
  {
     int mem2;
  }nest_var2;
}outer_var;

int main()
{
    int offset;
    struct nest_str1 * addr;
    offset=sizeof(int); // There is only one integer mem1 in nest_str1
    addr=(struct nest_str1 *)((char *) & (outer_var.nest_var2) - (char          *)offset);
    addr->mem1=333;
    printf("\n\nThe value of mem1 is %d\n\n",addr->mem1);
    return 0;
}
```